# Is there a cost effective way of backing up Firebase Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

As I understand it, backing up a Firestore database incurs a read for every document. That seems incredibly expensive.

For example, let's say I have note taking app with 1000 users and every day each user creates 100 docs and reads 100 docs. The cost per month would be:

```
reads = 1000 * 100 * 30 * 0.036/100000 = $1.08 per month
writes = 1000 * 100 * 30 * 0.108/100000 = $3.24 per month
```

That seems very reasonable, even inexpensive.

But let's say I want to create a daily backup to ensure customers don't lose their notes in case of some sort of failure.

After 1 year of use, the monthly cost of a daily backup will be:

```
reads = 1000 * 100 * 365 * 30 * 0.036/100000 = $394.20 per month
```

And it'll only get more and more expensive over time!

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to handle this? I know that the Realtime Database has backups that only cost storage, but I think for this type of app, Firestore is better in all regards except for backup costs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I apologize for answering this question like this, but you have your math wrong. You multiplied by 30 and 365. Which would give you the cost for about 30 years. Your cost to back up would be

```
reads = 1000 * 100 * 365 * 0.036/100000 = $13.14 per year
```

Correct me if I'm wrong. I may have misunderstood your problem.

Edit0: By the way, you can easily backup using the [Cloud Firestore managed export and import service](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import).

Edit1:

GCloud offers a service called BigQuery (its Google's framework for data analysis). Previously, what I used to do is what you describe in your question, exporting entire collections from Firestore to analyse in BigQuery. But now, you can configure real-time synchronicity between BigQuery and Firestore.

> With the “Export Collections to BigQuery” extension, you can send
> realtime, incremental updates from any Firestore collection to
> BigQuery. It will listen for document changes in your specified
> Firestore collection, then exports the changes into BigQuery. In other
> words, the data in BigQuery is a mirror of your content in Firestore.

This functionality is described [here](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-configure-the-export-collections-to-bigquery-extension-and-use-sql-full-power-on-your-f3565d809b96) (medium.com).

Edit2:

As discussed, the concern came up that should the data become corrupt in Firestore, it'll probably affect the data in BigQuery since it's updating in real-time.

To solve this, I recommend using [Cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to schedule daily exports from BigQuery. Exports from BigQuery are free of charge.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nizar. Your math above would be the cost of backing up the database once per year. I think most people would want more frequent backups. My math is for daily backups, so after one year of use, there would be 1000 * 100 * 365 documents, but backing that up once per day for 30 days gives the monthly cost of $394.20. It would be possible to reduce cost by backing up less frequently, but I think daily is a common backup cadence.

Comment: You're correct, but I wouldn't do it that way. I edited the answer, see if it helps you

Comment: Using bigquery as a backup tool is an interesting idea. So is the process you envision this: 1) mirror firestore data into bigquery using the extension, and 2) performing daily data exports of the entire database from bigquery to cloud storage. I'll need do some more research to see whether this works and what the costs of that backup process will look like. Thanks!

Comment: Forgot step 3) in case of firestore data loss, find a way to get exported bigquery data back into firestore.

Comment: Well, not really daily mirroring, its real-time listening and copying. So it's kind of like writing to 2 databases. After your data is available in bigquery and you want to import it into firestore in a catastrophe situation, you can export it from bigquery in .overall_export_metadata format (file extension). And you can import files of this type into firestore.

Comment: I think the important thing I need to figure out is whether bigquery can do daily backups/exports. let's say there's some bug in production that deletes a bunch of documents by mistake. then bigquery's copy will also reflect that mistake which makes it ineffective as a backup.

Comment: True, but YOU need to export daily from BigQuery. It doesn't cost you money to export from BigQuery "There are no charges for exporting data from BigQuery, but you do incur charges for storing the exported data in Cloud Storage."  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to automate that with something like cloud functions. I appreciate these ideas, I'm going to do more research to see if this is a viable strategy. Thanks!

Comment: I'll save you some time, there is a way to automate it in crontab. Schedule a crontab script on your computer to execute once per day. This script will simply have the export command using the gcloud command line.

Comment: @stevenkkim Were you able to implement this?

Comment: @Nizar any approximation on what the pricing would be for using BigQuery(considering the usage constraints mentioned by OP)?

Comment: As @Nizar initially said, your calculation is wrong.
1000 Users * 100 Documents per user * 365 days in a year * Your Firestore read rate = 13,14. Divided by the 12 months of the year = 1,095 (per month).
You could even get a rough estimate, using the result of your own calculation of your monthly upkeep for reads, which was 1,08. Just multiply that by 12 months in a year = 12,96.

Comment: @Nizar have you been able to successfully restore from BigQuery? The Export To BigQuery firestore extension is an awesome and cheap way to do incremental backups, and because all operations are timestamped, you can grab a snapshot of the database at any arbitrary time.  However, I am struggling to find ways of restoring from bigquery.

Answer (score 6):

2023 August 30:

You can now [Back up and restore data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/backups) by use firestore backup feature without charged by each document read or write, It work with different pricing model see [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#select-region).

Billing of [Backup data and restore operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#backup_data_and_restore_operations) document says

> If you enable backups, you are charged for the storage of your
> database backups. The storage size for a backup is equal to the
> storage size of the database when you took the backup.
>
> Storage costs for backups are in GiB/month and calculated daily. Cloud
> Firestore measures the size of your database backups once a day. Over
> the period of a month, these sample points are averaged to calculate
> the backup storage size. This average value is multiplied by the unit
> price of backups (GiB-month).
>
> When you perform a restore operation, Cloud Firestore measures the
> size of the backup for the restore operation. The size of the backup
> is multiplied by the unit price of restore operations (GiB).

To create a daily backup schedule:

```
gcloud alpha firestore backups schedules create \
--database='DATABASE_ID' \
--recurrence=daily \
--retention=RETENTION_PERIOD
```

To restore data from a database backup:

```
gcloud alpha firestore databases restore \
--source-backup=projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION/backups/BACKUP_ID \
--destination-database='DATABASE_ID'
```

Comment: Hallelujah! It took forever for Google to implement this, but I'm glad they did. Thanks for letting me know!