# Firestore backup with Stream Collections to BigQuery-extension and BigQuery export, how and in what format is this done?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

In short: Firestore backup with [Stream Collections to BigQuery](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-firestore-bigquery-export)-extension and BigQuery export, how and in what format is this done?

I have a project using Firestore and it implements [Stream Collections to BigQuery](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-firestore-bigquery-export)-extension for great data analysis possibilities and Data Studio.
In case of data loss or some catastrophe situation the problem will be forwarded to BigQuery as same data is in two places due the extension. But in BigQuery I can use [time travel](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/time-travel) to get data from any point of last 7 days.

Now after reading this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69472913/is-there-a-cost-effective-way-of-backing-up-firebase-firestore) backups from Firestore to GCS will start to cost a lot. So it seems streaming data to BigQuery and having it as backup with usage of time travel functionality or doing automatic backup to gcs.

What way should I export BigQuery data and import it to Firestore and is it possible to export in ".overall_export_metadata"-format to import it straight away to Firestore if needed. In the comment of the question it was said:

> After your data is available in bigquery and you want to import it
> into firestore in a catastrophe situation, you can export it from
> bigquery in .overall_export_metadata format (file extension). And you
> can import files of this type into firestore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**2 Things:**

- As you said, firestore export is costly: it will cost you read for each doc. There is currently no way to have a backup easily.

If you still want to place automated backups you can see that here: [https://fireship.io/snippets/firestore-automated-backups/#:~:text=As%20of%20today%2C%20Firestore%20does,imported%20to%20replace%20lost%20data](https://fireship.io/snippets/firestore-automated-backups/#:%7E:text=As%20of%20today%2C%20Firestore%20does,imported%20to%20replace%20lost%20data). (as far as I know for firestore database there is no "OOTB" way to make backups for firestore DB)

- To import big query: export big query data on your bucket as mentioned. Then in gcp go to https://console.cloud.google.com/firestore/import-export, select `import`, browse the file exported from bigQuery, and it should import the firebase data

Comment: Okey thank you for explanation. Just to understand, do you mean that the export BigQuery data to bucket is done through exporting csv/json (which can be done through the Gui) and that can be imported with Firestore's import method?